# "Us Americans" or "We Americans"?

Tags: personal-pronouns, grammatical-case, appositives

If there is a group of individuals identified by a name, what's the right way for one of the group to refer to them all?

For example, if one of a group of 10 Americans wants to refer to the group, is it more correct to say "Us Americans" or "We Americans"?

Comment: Is FumbleFingers' bounty text hinting that Gnawme's answer is incorrect in Britain?

Comment: @GEdgar As far as I understand it, your answer is perfect, so FumbleFingers might be hinting at something else?

Comment: I'm not sure a 13k-views-question warrants a "not enough attention" bounty without further explanation. @FumbleFingers, can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Pardon me if these are stupid questions, but why was this question not closed -- a google news search gave me examples in seconds.  And why the bounty?

Comment: I forgot to ask -- also, why did this question get so many up votes?  I really don't get it.

Comment: @Araucaria - Wouldn't step one be to contribute an answer you consider correct?

Answer (score 32):

What are the Americans doing?

Apply the usual "we vs. us" test: Remove any nouns and adjectives between **we/us** and the verb, and test.

> [**We/Us**] *drink* beer cold : **We** Americans drink beer cold.
>
> The Aussies *call* [**we/us**] Seppos : The Aussies call **us** Americans Seppos.

The same test applies when referring to any group collectively:

> [**We**/**Us**] *recite* poetry to appreciative audiences: **We**
>   Vogons recite poetry to appreciative audiences.
>
> The "Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy" *describes* [**we**/**us**] in
>   highly disparaging terms: The "Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy"
>   describes **us** Vogons in highly disparaging terms. (A lawsuit is pending. In triplicate.)

Comment: It's not that I disagree, but I find your answer waay too complicated for a simple question.

Comment: @aparente001 It was much simpler (everything before the EDIT paragraph), but a bounty was offered, so I expanded the answer. I don't know whether I can post two answers for the same question.

Comment: Yes, you can.  Note that another reason I offered an alternative answer is that I didn't find your example sentences super clear.  (Maybe it's just me.)

Answer (score 7):

To address the points that @FumbleFingers raises in his bounty:

Merriam-Webster Unabridged offers these observations in its definition of the pronominal **us** (albeit not without some nose-holding, and a few pokes at "grammarians"):

> **f** — used by speakers on all educational levels and by many reputable writers though disapproved by some grammarians in the
>   predicate after forms of *be*, in comparisons after *than* and **as**
>   when the first term in the comparison is the subject of a verb, and in
>   other positions where it is itself neither the subject of a verb nor
>   the object of a verb or preposition:
>
> - *the miraculous generation which is **us*** [Arnold Bennett]
> - *you are bigger and stronger than **us** women* [K. A. Menninger]
> - ***us*** and our little problems
>
> **g** (1) — used chiefly in substandard speech and formerly also by reputable writers as part of the compound subject of a verb or
>   especially with an immediately following appositive noun as the
>   subject of a verb which it does not immediately precede
>
> - *our neighbors and **us** don't like that*
> - ***us*** kids were always given a swallow [Walter Karig]
>
> (2) *chiefly dialectal* — used as the subject of a verb from which it
>   is not separated by other words
>
> - ***us*** lived in a two-story house [Ralph Ellison]
>
> **h** — used like the adjective *our* with a gerund by speakers and writers on all educational levels though disapproved by some
>   grammarians
>
> - *she approved of **us** getting summer jobs*

Likewise, M-W Unabridged defines these (ahem) non-standard usages of the pronominal **we**:

> **3a** *dialectal, chiefly England* :  **us** — used emphatically as object of a verb or preposition
>
> - *to poor **we** thine enmity's most capital* [Shakespeare]
> - *the likes of **we***
>
> **b** *chiefly substandard* :  **us** — used in a compound object or in apposition with a following noun
>
> - *he disturbed those in the dining room, those in the hall, and even **we**    who had retired upstairs*
> - *as to **we** men* [Fanny Burney]

Comment: @Araucaria: Yeah - excellent result all round! (ty again, Gnawme! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers My pleasure. Glad to be able to contribute now and again.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with the rule of thumb described elsewhere which recommends using "we Americans" or "us Americans" depending on whether the context calls for the subject or object pronoun. This is the standard practice, as corroborated by a corpus search.

For example, if you search for "we Americans" versus "us Americans" in the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) and glance at the results, you'll see that "we Americans" is *almost* always used in subject position while "us Americans" is *almost* always used in object position. Here is the screenshot for "we Americans":

[image]

Here is the screenshot for "us Americans":

[image]

Prima facie, "we Americans" occurs in subject position, while "us Americans" occurs in object position. This supports the rule of thumb I described above.

That said, there *is* a convention in English regarding the modification of subject pronouns like 'I', 'you', 'he', 'she', and 'we'. These pronouns are allowed to appear as subjects *pre*-nominally modified by adjectives only if they are transformed into their *object* variant. For example, compare:

1. The drunk *me* is a nightmare.
2. The real *her* is better than the fake her.
3. Blonde *him* looks better than brunette him.
4. New York *us* is having a harder time paying the bills than did rural Iowa us.

with

5. *The drunk *I* is a nightmare.
6. *The real *she* is better than the fake she.
7. *Blonde *he* looks better than brunette he.
8. *New York *we* is having a harder time paying the bills than did rural Iowa we.

The reason the object pronoun is necessary may have to do with the fact that this construction is ultimately rooted in an ellipsis which requires it (for example, "the real *version of* me").

I suspect that the existence of this convention might lead some people to feel comfortable using "us Americans" in subject position. For example:

9. Us Americans love guns.

This is certainly acceptable in some dialects, although I haven't found any corpus examples yet. It certainly doesn't sound bad to my ear.

***NOTE:*** I'm not saying that subject-positioned "us Americans" is the same kind of construction as "New York us" (syntactically, they seem to be quite different). All I'm saying is that the existence of the latter might influence a speaker's judgment regarding the former (it might lead him to think that the former is acceptable).

---

As a historical note, the linguist Otto Jespersen was probably the first to think about constructions like "we Americans." He treated them as involving appositional relative clauses that had undergone something like ellipsis (for example "we, *who are* Americans"). Postal (1966) argued against this analysis, as does Elbourne (2005).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46214/discussion-on-answer-by-silenus-us-americans-or-we-americans).

Answer (score 2):

If you would normally put "us" in the sentence, say "**us Americans.**"

If you would normally put "we" in the sentence, say "**we Americans.**"

Examples (recent quotes from U.S. President Barack Obama):

> "Together there is nothing *we Americans* cannot overcome.”  (9/11/16)
>
> "All of *us Americans* should be troubled by these shootings." (7/7/16)

Comment: I am not sure where you found this rule. However, you need to be careful because there are a lot of bogus rules like this one advocated on the wilds of the internet. This particular rule does not describe real usage in standard English.

Comment: Another example, though, also from Mr Obama: "We also agree, us Americans and Canadians, that wealthy countries like ours cannot reach our full potential while others remain mired in poverty." (6/2916)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the word "American" from the proposed sentence, and the correct pronoun will be obvious to any English speaker.

> Nobody here but us chickens.