# Why do we say " talk show" not " talking show"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage, differences, adjectives

In English, why do we usually say "talk show" not "talking show"?

Comment: Whoever heard of a show that can talk? ;-)

Comment: Haha , I got it, but should we use an adjective before the the noun " show" ?

Comment: not necessarily: a music show is a show about music, a cop show is about cops etc.

Comment: Seriously, what @Jim said. I never heard of *tracks* that can *race* either. That's why we usually talk about ***racing cars** on **race tracks***, not ***race cars** on **racing tracks***.

Comment: Oh， it is like a composed word or noun. Thank you very much for your replies.

Comment: @Paulo: I'd call it a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) usage - the reference is to the noun ***a talk*** = *a [formal] discussion, presentation, negotiation, etc.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers In British-English it's generally called a 'Chat-Show', where **a chat** =  *an informal conversation*. Who knew us Brits were so much more casual about our televised discussions...

Comment: @Spagirl: Well, we [Brits](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+a+chat%2Chave+a+talk&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20a%20chat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20a%20talk%3B%2Cc0) are more likely to *have a **chat*** where [Americans](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+a+chat%2Chave+a+talk&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20a%20chat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20a%20talk%3B%2Cc0) would *have a **talk***. But ***show*** always sounds a bit "American" to me in these contexts.

Comment: Mainly because it's been "talk show" since the stone ages (or at least the radio era).

Comment: (There is no "grammar police" which chooses such terms -- they are selected by the public at large, based on whatever they find most familiar and sufficiently descriptive.  The public will tend to prefer shorter, easier to pronounce terms over longer, more awkward ones, hence "talk show" vs "talking show".)

Comment: @Spagirl: Noting our different pronoun choices there led me to [“Us Americans” or “We Americans”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56089/), which I think needs a bounty to gain more attention. According to the only upvoted answer there, your version is apparently "invalid". But as a fellow Brit, obviously ***I*** have no problem with it - it's just a quirk of fate that I happened to use the "valid" version myself (I didn't notice until *after* I'd made my post).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I wonder if there is a geographic range accord the UK, or whether it's a formality register thing. I'm Scottish with Lancastrian roots and a tendency to be a bit 'Coronation St' hammy at times. :D

Answer (score -1):

There is talking in almost every show, while a "talk show" features talk over any other kind of action or appeal.